# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int': program to change and display C to F

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to write a script to prompt user for a Celsius temperature then print out the Fahrenheit equivalent

```
x = input("Enter the Celsius Temparature:")
print("Its", u"x\u00B0", "out there")
y = (((9*x)/5)+32)
print("The Fahrenheit Equivalent is:{0:0.3f}" .format(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you typed in digits doesn't make `x` an `int`; `input` always returns a string, which you'll need to convert to the appropriate integer before using it to do math.

Comment: So I changed the code like this                                                                              x = input("Enter the Celsius Temparature:")
print("Its", u"int(x)\u00B0", "out there")
y = ((9*int(x))/5)+32
print("The Fahrenheit Equivalent is:{0:0.3f}" .format(y))                                        and the output I got is                                                                                        Enter the Celsius Temparature:10
Its int(x)° out there
The Fahrenheit Equivalent is:50.000    How to get 10 in place of int(x) ?

Comment: It wasn't printing the value of x before; why would you expect it to now?

Comment: I know it wasn't printing 10 before. My question here is how can I print 10 instead of x ?